# How to fix 404 error when using SEO URLs with htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, url, slug

I have pages in root directory/pages
pages like object.php

On these pages I get seo_url via GET and in the script on the object.php page I search for this seo_url and get the id for it via a database query

the problem is that when you go to mysite.com/object/car/, a 404 page is redirected. Why does this happen and how to make SEO urls correctly in my case?

Thats my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Options +FollowSymLinks
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag allow_url_fopen off
php_value error_reporting 0

# SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#catalogue
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^object/(.*)$ object.php?seo_url=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url_param=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and thats my index.php

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = explode('?', $url)[0];
$pages = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pages'); 

$found = false;

foreach ($pages as $page) {  
    
    if ($page !== "." && $page !== "…") { 
        $page_name = pathinfo($page, PATHINFO_FILENAME); 
        if ($url === "/" . $page_name) { 
            include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pages/" . $page; 
            $found = true; 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
}

if ($url === '/') { 
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pages/main.php"; 
    $found = true; 
}

if (!$found) { 
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pages/404.php"; 
}
```

in object.php

```
$seo_url = $_GET["seo_url"];

$id = $objects->seo_url_object($seo_url);  (here is a sql query to search for id by seo_url)
```

Please help. When I follow the link mysite.com/object?seo_url=car everything works correctly, when I follow the link mysite.com/object/car/ - error 404

Comment: `/object/car/` is looking for a folder, have you tried `/object/car`?

Comment: @brombeer Yeah, it's still 404.

Comment: `/object/car/` gets rewritten to `/object.php?seo_url=car/` - and if your database only contains `car`, not `car/`, then your query likely won't find anything.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry for that typo, of course the link used is mysite.com/object/car and the problem here is either in the htaccess rule or in the conditions of my index.php I just can't find the error(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have provide code just check it.

```
echo $currentURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];;

// Split the URL by '/' into an array
$urlParts = explode('/', $currentURL);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($urlParts);
$requestPage = "";
if(isset($urlParts[1]) && $urlParts[1] == "object")
{
  $requestPage = $urlParts[2];
}



$pages = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pages'); 
//echo "<pre>";
$found = false;
//print_r($pages);
foreach ($pages as $page) {  
    //print_r($page);
    if ($page !== "." && $page !== "…") { 
        $page_name = pathinfo($page, PATHINFO_FILENAME); 
        print_r([$requestPage,$page_name]);
        if ($requestPage == $page_name) { 
          echo "found page";
            include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pages/" . $page; 
            $found = true; 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
}
if ($url === '/') { 
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pages/main.php"; 
    $found = true; 
}

if (!$found) { 
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pages/404.php"; 
}
```

after success you have remove echo, print_r.
[local system screen short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/418au.png)

Answer (score -1):

Hi I Think first step is that you have to check .htacess working or not
so using this link check .htaccess enable ot not
https://askubuntu.com/questions/421233/enabling-htaccess-file-to-rewrite-path-not-working

[htaccess checking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LGoE.png)

Comment: Yes, it definitely works, it definitely redirects all requests to index.php, so the other rules work too.

Comment: okay then issue in  $url = explode('?', $url)[0]; because when you call mysite.com/object/car/  it can not  explode proper value.

Comment: i think you have spit with / link this

$currentURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Split the URL by '/' into an array
$urlParts = explode('/', $currentURL);
check if get paramater then pass.

Comment: Sorry for that typo, of course the link used is mysite.com/object/car and the problem here is either in the htaccess rule or in the conditions of my index.php I just can't find the error(